# How to make github page visible to search engines without using Jekyll?

Tags: github

I have a github website which ends with .github.io . It is made with plain HTML and CSS with little JS. I waited for more than a week but it didn't get indexed by Google. Even searching for its URL on Google doesn't give result.

Googling this question gave me only solution using Jekyll. Is there anyway to achieve this without it ? I already tried submitting it to pinging sites.

Edit : This applies to not just Google but other search engines too. Eg: Bing, DuckDuckGo.

Answer (score 1):

Submit your site to **google webmaster tools**!

Comment: That only solves the problem for Google. Other search engines like Bing amd DuckDuckGo also do not index the site. So isn't there a proper solution to this ?